# NHibernate mapping SQL-VIEW without unique identifier

Tags: vb.net, nhibernate, mapping, nhibernate-mapping

I have a **read-only** mssql-**view**, and I want to map it to nhibernate (using **hbm.xml** files).
The view is a select that joins two tables. For give an abstract-insight, the select is something like this:

```
SELECT A.Id As A_ID, B.Id As B_ID,
       A.AttributeA, B.AttributeB,

FROM A INNER JOIN B ON 
     A.Id = B.RootID
```

It's a one-to-many relationship between A and B (B entries are dependant/leafs of A entries).

I'm using nhibernate's hbm.xml files, and I can't make it to work.

I'd gladly appreciate if someone can enlight me of the kind of XML that I have to use, I guess that as my view has no ID, I have to create a composite-nhibernate id (wich will be the ids os A and B together) but I couldn't make it to work.
Also the view is READ ONLY so I think that should make the solution easier.

I'm asking the question because none of the others on the site answered this issue (some use fluent-nhibernate,I'm with XML mapping files)

thanks in advance.

Comment: What errors were you getting with the composite ids defined?

Comment: In this abstract example I tried to give, there is a conceptual error: as the B entries are dependant on only one A entry, then the ID of B could be used as the ID of the joined tables (as there will not exist any B entries more than once), so there was no need of a composite id.

Comment: ... However, a composite id still would be necessary if the join is a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and not an inner join as in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Andy, that lead me to the final solution.
I will put the hbm.xml template with my domain-model entities.
All the columns I'm mapping are varchars/strings (hence my composite ID consist of two strings):

```
    <class name="Model.Projects.ProjectsLoansView"
           table="V_PROJECTSLOANS" mutable="false">

    <composite-id>
      <key-property name="Number" column="Number"/>
      <key-property name="OperationNumber" column="OperationNumber" />
    </composite-id>

    <property name="Name" column="Name" not-null="false"/>

  </class>
```

But the mapping was not enough. Nhibernate requests to Override the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` function, I will put the exact code of my working VB.Net class that correspond to this XML:

```
  Public Class ProjectsLoansView

        Public Overridable Property Number As String
        Public Overridable Property OperationNumber As String

        Public Overridable Property Name As String

        Public Overloads Overrides Function Equals(ByVal obj As Object) As Boolean

            If (IsNothing(obj)) Then Return False

            Dim t As ProjectsLoansView = CType(obj, ProjectsLoansView)

            If ((Me.Number = t.Number) And (Me.OperationNumber = t.OperationNumber)) Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        End Function

        Public Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer
            'TODO: check how to override properly GetHashCode. As is a-read only view it doesn't matter here
            Return MyBase.GetHashCode()
        End Function

    End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mapping file should look like:

```
<class name="blah" mutable="false">
  <composite-id>
    <key-property name="A_ID"/>
    <key-property name="B_ID"/>
  </composite-id>

  <property name="A.Attribute" />
  <property name="B.Attribute" />
</class>
```

Does that map correctly to your view? Please let me know what else you've tried if not.

Comment: thanks this template lead me to the solution, as I could get more detailed nhibernate exceptions to solve the problem